# What is this Timepicker directive looking for in Firefox?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs-directive, timepicker

I am attempting to use a timepicker directive in an angular.js webapp. It works without any issues in Chrome, but in Firefox I get the following error:

```
"Timepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date."
```

What would this directive be looking for in Firefox that it isn't in Chrome?

Edit:
I still get the same error after doing the following in my html:

```
<timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
<pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>
```

and this in my controller:

```
$scope.mytime = new Date();

$scope.hstep = 1;
$scope.mstep = 15;

$scope.ismeridian = true;
$scope.toggleMode = function() {
    $scope.ismeridian = ! $scope.ismeridian;
};

$scope.update = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours( 14 );
    d.setMinutes( 0 );
    $scope.mytime = d;
};

$scope.changed = function () {
    $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
};
```

but I am still getting the same error. And I am in Firefox 35 as well. Chrome works flawlessly with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify what timepicker directive you're using, and some code showing how you're using it?  If this is the one from angular-ui, are you setting up the ng-model as a new Date() object?

I've tested this in Chrome (latest), Firefox 35.0.1, and IE 10.0 and it's working for me on all of them.

http://plnkr.co/edit/O4UUzfHLlyRkEL9SFX8m?p=preview

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.*" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
    <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.mytime = new Date();

  $scope.hstep = 1;
  $scope.mstep = 15;

  $scope.ismeridian = true;
  $scope.toggleMode = function() {
      $scope.ismeridian = ! $scope.ismeridian;
  };

  $scope.update = function() {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setHours( 14 );
      d.setMinutes( 0 );
      $scope.mytime = d;
  };

  $scope.changed = function () {
      $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
  };

});
```

Comment: Sure. This is the timepicker that I am using: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker.

I am using it like so: 

'<timedropdown time="EndTime"></timedropdown>'

which is populated by 

'<div class="timeWidget">
 <timepicker class="timePicker" ng-model="time" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian">
 </timepicker>
</div>'
'

Comment: On your model, is $scope.time initialized like $scope.time = new Date();  ?

Comment: Yes, I am initializing it like :$scope.EndTime = new Date();

This works correctly in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: What version of Firefox, angular, and ui-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I updated answer to provide a plnkr, tested in IE, Chrome and Firefox on my machine and I didn't get the error.  Does my example work with your Firefox?

Comment: @martin122089 I changed my plnkr example above to use the exact code you have in your example, and it's working flawlessly for me in Firefox 35.0.1, I don't think it's a browser issue.  Can you go to my link and see if it works for you?  If you don't get the error on mine then it's not your browser, could be the specific version of ui-bootstrap or angularjs you are using has an error.

Comment: I think you might be right. That plnkr works in my FF as well. I will keep investigating. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it helps, I used angular 1.2.28, and ui-bootstrap 0.12 for my example.